# setlocale in Laravel with docker

Tags: php, laravel, docker

Hello my Laravel project runs with docker. But when I set up my date with setlocal in my language. Laravel displays the result in English `@php setlocale(LC_ALL, 'fr_FR'); echo strftime("%A %d %B %Y");@endphp`

I'm pretty sure this issue is cause by the container, but I don't know how to fix it.

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you input `locale -a` on you host pc, you will surely find something like `fr_FR`. But in container, by default, most of image won't provide French lang.

Next is a minimal example for you to install french lang, FYI:

**test.php:**

```
<?php setlocale(LC_ALL, 'fr_FR'); echo strftime("%A %d %B %Y");
```

**Dockerfile:**

```
FROM php

COPY test.php /

RUN apt-get update; \
    apt-get install -y locales; \
    sed -i '/^#.* fr_FR.* /s/^#//' /etc/locale.gen; \
    locale-gen

RUN locale -a
RUN php /test.php
```

**Execution:**

```
$ docker build -t abc:1 .
Sending build context to Docker daemon  3.072kB
Step 1/5 : FROM php
 ---> 7a9e4bdd6171
Step 2/5 : COPY test.php /
 ---> 705d4f7695e4
Step 3/5 : RUN apt-get update;     apt-get install -y locales;     sed -i '/^#.* fr_FR.* /s/^#//' /etc/locale.gen;     locale-gen
 ---> Running in 1c9d6012e7b9
...
Generating locales (this might take a while)...
Generation complete.
Generating locales (this might take a while)...
  fr_FR.ISO-8859-1... done
  fr_FR.UTF-8... done
  fr_FR.ISO-8859-15@euro... done
Generation complete.
Removing intermediate container 1c9d6012e7b9
 ---> ff1733e34ad0
Step 4/5 : RUN locale -a
 ---> Running in bd21cd6c14e8
C
C.UTF-8
POSIX
fr_FR
fr_FR.iso88591
fr_FR.iso885915@euro
fr_FR.utf8
fr_FR@euro
french
Removing intermediate container bd21cd6c14e8
 ---> 699d9918f95f
Step 5/5 : RUN php /test.php
 ---> Running in 49316730728c
mardi 22 juin 2021Removing intermediate container 49316730728c
 ---> c8cc561fd306
Successfully built c8cc561fd306
Successfully tagged abc:1
```

**Explanation:**

- By default, `fr_FR` is commented in `/etc/locale.gen`, we could use `sed` to uncomment it.
- Next, use `locale-gen` to generate French lang.
- After french lang installed in your container, you could get `mardi 22 juin 2021` when run the php file.

Comment: Thank you for the good explication and your time taken.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure the locales package is installed in your docker image.

```
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y locales
```